# Revit : Where to find the Navisworks Export Add-In

Tags: autodesk, revit, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-navisworks

Can someone tell me where I can find the Revit -> Navisworks export or how I can turn it on. Is it something that can be downloaded and installed?

Reading this blog post [Link](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2016/06/getting-room-information-for-revit-models-in-the-forge-viewer.html)

It talks about how the Autodesk-Viewer can see the room as a object only when it converted as a Navisworks file. There seems to be a Revit add in that allows for export of a Navisworks file. I can not seem to find how to add that add in to Revit so that it shows up in the Add-In ribbon.

I am using Autodesk Revit Architecture 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download this exporter [here](http://www.autodesk.com/products/navisworks/autodesk-navisworks-nwc-export-utility). There are some differences if you translate to Viewer from .rvt (Revit) or from .nwc (Navisworks). I remember doing  some testing with levels, and .nwc expose this better than .rvt. You mentioned Rooms, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for.  Heads up to anyone else its 600 meg download and 3gig uncompressed, but works and will give you revit room , and  room sqft in the metadataproperties.json after nwc  to svf conversion. Also note that the folder structure is different then the rvt conversion